# vuetify.js.map HTTP 404

Tags: webpack, vuetify.js

I have this error with vuetify :
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for webpack:///node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
I use webpack

I try to create vutify component, some elements are not displayed correctly, it seems css was missing

I have been see in sources under Google Chrome and I can see the vuetify/dist directory but it does not contain the vuetify.js.map file.
I used the following project: github.com/TrilonIO/aspnetcore-Vue-starter

Is there anything to add to the webpack.config.js file to manage the map file?

I have this for map file in webpack.config.js :

```
plugins: [
      new VueLoaderPlugin(),
      new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
        context: __dirname,
        manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
      })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
      // Plugins that apply in development builds only
      new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
        moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
      })
    ] : [
      extractCSS,
      // Compress extracted CSS.
      new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
        cssProcessorOptions: {
          safe: true
        }
      })
    ])
```

Thank you so much. I understood where the problem comes from: I forgot to use the v-app tag

I have another problem when building and publishing the site on IIS.
Vuetify components do not appear as if the library was not installed ...

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

## Updated Answer

Thank you for the additional information! I was able to install the [ASP.NetCore Vuejs Starter](https://github.com/TrilonIO/aspnetcore-Vue-starter) and get it running with Vuetify successfully. Here are the steps I took:

1. I installed the following NPM packages (although you may not need all of them):

```
$ npm install -D vuetify sass sass-loader fibers deepmerge @mdi/js @mdi/font
```

2. Here's a link to [a gist of my `webpack.config.js` file](https://gist.github.com/morphatic/055fb7db128470a41d160eaee59855c5). You should **NOT** need to configure webpack to produce `vuetify.js.map` as this already should be downloaded in `node_modules/vuetify/dist/`
3. The `ClientApp/plugins/vuetify.js` file contains:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdiSvg'
  }
}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

4. Then in `ClientApp/app.js` I added `import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'` and added the `vuetify` object to the main `Vue` instance
5. I updated the template in `ClientApp/components/app-root.vue` to:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer app clipped :value="collapsed">
      <nav-menu params="route: route"></nav-menu>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-app-bar app clipped-left>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon
        @click.stop="collapsed = !collapsed"
      />
      <v-toolbar-title>
        Hello, World!
      </v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-footer app>
      &copy; 2020 Testy McTesterface
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

6. I added these two lines to the `<head>` section in `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`:

```html
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@@mdi/font@@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

7. Finally, I began updating `ClientApp/components/nav-menu.vue` to be:

```html
<template>
    <div class="main-nav">
        <v-list-item
            v-for="(route, index) in routes"
            :key="index"
            :to="route.path"
        >
            <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>{{ route.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-action>
            <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>
                    {{ route.display }}
                </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
    </div>
</template>
```

Clearly there are still a lot of bugs that need to be worked out, but I think that should give you a good start.

## Previous Answer (before extra info provided)

I don't have enough detail to know exactly what's causing your problem, but here are some clues that might help you:

The "scheme" of a "URL scheme" is the part *before* the `://`. So in a url like `http://example.com`, the scheme would be `http://`. There are lots of different URL schemes in common use like `ftp://` (for FTP), or `mysql://` (for MySQL databases). In this case, Chrome DevTools is trying to open a URL that has the scheme `webpack://`, but it's claiming not to know what that means.

When you run a VueJs app using the built-in webpack dev server (i.e. by running `vue run serve` from the command line), when you try to view the source of one of these files in your browser (like in this screenshot), webpack serves the source code of these files to your browser, and they tend to use the `webpack:///` URL scheme.

[image: screenshot showing JavaScript source files in Chrome DevTools for a site being run by the webpack dev server]

Here are some problems you might be having:

1. The webpack dev server stopped running, so Chrome can no longer access the file
2. Your dev server is not configured correctly. Was it working before? Can you undo some of the recent changes you made to see if you can figure out what caused the problem?

If you provide more details, I might have more luck diagnosing the problem. In general, when you ask questions here, the more details you provide, the better!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I have been see in sources under Google Chrome and I can see the vuetify / dist directory but it does not contain the vuetify.js.map file.

I used the following project: https://github.com/TrilonIO/aspnetcore-Vue-starter

Is there anything to add to the webpack.config.js file to manage the map file?

Comment: Thank you so much.
I understood where the problem comes from: I forgot to use the v-app tag

Comment: But I have another problem when building and publishing the site on IIS.
Vuetify components do not appear as if the library was not installed ...